# Throwable not catching include and require

Tags: php, include, require, throwable

I have a problem. Throwable doesn't return an exception for require or include functions. Is there any way to "fix" it? Code:

```
try {
    include 'non-existent-file.php';
    #require 'non-existent-file.php';
} catch (\Throwable $ex) {
    die('include error');
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Who told you that something will be thrown here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using `file_exists ( string $filename )`...

```
if ( file_exists('non-existent-file.php') === true)   {
    include 'non-existent-file.php';
} 
else {
    die('include error');
}
```

Comment: Of course, that's what I care about catching an exception and display my own message.